# VPN/Internet access on another interface

Tags: linux, networking, routing, openvpn

I have a Linux server with two network interfaces. They are both connected to two different networks with different private IP addresses.

One interface(eth0) is connected to a secure network, where I have no Internet access at all. The primary objective of this server is to serve users on this network. There are are users from several different subnets accessing the server over this interface.

The other interface(eth1) is connected to an insecure network and here I have unrestricted Internet access which is required for a bunch of scripts I run on the server. I need to somehow route all DNS requests and all connections to Internet to go through eth1.

I also have openvpn client installed on the server and I want it to go over eth1 to my VPN server running on Internet.

If eth0 was only accessing a single subnet, I could've configured eth1 as default route and set a static route over eth0 but not sure if that would work in this case?

What would be my best option here?

Comment: What's your problem exactly?

Comment: Sorry, I thought that was obvious - when I set eth0 as default route I can't get on Internet and when I set eth1 as default route I can't access the local subnets.

Comment: the default route should be go through eth1, and set static routes on eth0 for reaching the secure lan. But you wrote the same in the post.

Comment: I can't do that because there are multiple subnets in the secure LAN and they could change often. Do I have any other options? Is it possible to force DNS requests, requests to port 80 and 443 and openvpn to use  eth1 somehow?

Comment: often changing subnets??? what? Local subnets must have 10.0.0.0/8 or 192.168.0.0/16 or 172.16.0.0 - 172.31.255.255 .

Comment: You are right, I just set iptables rules for the entire subnets and everything works fine!